# jQuery Expanding Nav Collapsing on Child Click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, nav

https://jsfiddle.net/aesya0g6/

Hello!

I have built an expanding nav, and it is running exactly how I want, except for the fact that it is collapsing on the click of the children.  I have tried switching where the jQuery is pointing, in hopes that this would resolve it, but have had no luck.  Where am I going wrong?

```
    $('.expandingNav').click(function(){
  if($(this).hasClass('expanded')){
    $(this).children('.hidden').slideUp();
    $(this).removeClass('expanded');
  }
  else{
    $(this).children('.hidden').slideDown();
    $(this).addClass('expanded');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You could check to see if the closest `ul` element has a parent element of `nav.sidebar`:

```
$('.expandingNav').on('click', function (e) {
    if ($(e.target).closest('ul').parent('nav.sidebar').length) {
        // ...
    }
});
```

[**Updated Example**](https://jsfiddle.net/6t3w2Lbc/)

```
$('.expandingNav').on('click', function (e) {
    if ($(e.target).closest('ul').parent('nav.sidebar').length) {
        if ($(this).hasClass('expanded')) {
            $(this).children('.hidden').slideUp();
            $(this).removeClass('expanded');
        } else {
            $(this).children('.hidden').slideDown();
            $(this).addClass('expanded');
        }
    }
});
```

---

Alternatively, you could also check to see if the parent element's next sibling is a `ul` element:

```
$('.expandingNav').on('click', function (e) {
    if ($(e.target).parent().next('ul').length) {
        // ...
    }
});
```

[**Updated Example**](https://jsfiddle.net/cy9vtwmf/)

```
$('.expandingNav').on('click', function (e) {
    if ($(e.target).parent().next('ul').length) {
        if ($(this).hasClass('expanded')) {
            $(this).children('.hidden').slideUp();
            $(this).removeClass('expanded');
        } else {
            $(this).children('.hidden').slideDown();
            $(this).addClass('expanded');
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: That worked perfectly!  However, noobie question, when did e get defined? I'm working on getting more familiar with JS and jQuery, and I coded the first part of all this on my own, but then things like e show up and I feel lost all over again.

Comment: @user3888851 Within the `click` event listener, `e` stands for 'event'. You can call this variable whatever you want, it is a parameter here .. `$('.expandingNav').on('click', function (e) { ... });` . If you look at the click method documentation, you will see that the object is called "eventData" .. http://api.jquery.com/click/

Comment: The documentation was a bit confusing - to clarify, e is always the data of the click?  What are other things I can pass to e besides e.target?

Comment: @user3888851 Essentially. `e` is just the event object that is assosicated with the click event. To see all the other properties, you could log `e`, and take a look.. `console.log(e)`.

Answer (score 1):

You could simple achieve it by adding:

```
//If the e.target is the same element as this, you've not clicked on a descendant.
if( e.target !== this ) return;
```

[updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/aesya0g6/10/)

Comment: @JoshCrozier you are correct, and i think it is a simple way if the UI could make a little concession. Of course you way is much more better, i also voted up answer you provided.

Answer (score 0):

When you click on an item's child the click event "bubbles up" to its parent thus triggering the click event which causes the slide up.
You should handle the click event on the children and use stopPropagation to avoid event bubbling.
Try something like this:

```
$('.expandingNav li').click(function(ev) { ev.stopPropagation(); })
```

Answer (score 0):

You shuold Avoid propagation anything Inside the element you click here in this case its `li` inside class `expandingNav`.

```
   $("li.expandingNav").on('click', function(e) {
  if($(this).hasClass('expanded')){
    $(this).children('.hidden').slideUp();
    $(this).removeClass('expanded');
  }
  else{
    $(this).children('.hidden').slideDown();
    $(this).addClass('expanded');
  }
    });
//On sub LI click , stop propagating. 
$("li.expandingNav li").on('click', function(e) {
 e.stopPropagation();
});
```

[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/aesya0g6/9/)

Answer (score 0):

dont bother yourself with confusing extra codes.

just put the listener on the a tag.

like this:

```
  $('.expandingNav').children('a').click(function(){
   var element = $(this).parent();
  if($(element).hasClass('expanded')){
    $(element).children('.hidden').slideUp();
    $(element).removeClass('expanded');
  }
  else{
    $(element).children('.hidden').slideDown();
    $(element).addClass('expanded');
  }
});
```